# How to include large resources with my iOS application

Tags: ios, file, storage, bundle

I am developing an iOS application where a requirement is for the user to view a known set of videos locally and without streaming. Because the videos do not live on a server of any kind on the internet, the files must be included with the app when installed.

The application will not be distributed on the app store, and will probably be distributed by some enterprise means (Airwatch, Apperian, etc). I am not yet sure which.

I am currently storing the videos under the app bundle's resources. I do not think this is sustainable because the size of all the videos will eventually be too large (we are thinking 10s of gigs).

What should I do?

Comment: Why are you not using a private server to save the files? Are the videos static or created by the user because I doubt that it's good to ship that much data with your app.

Comment: It will be a nightmare to update such an app for the users! Don't do it. Note: Enterprise builds must be update when certificate (3 years lifetime) and/or provisioning (1 year lifetime) changes.

Comment: Streaming isn't an option since the facilities have limited bandwidth, and client can't provision a server by release. Is there a bundle limit for apps distributed outside the app store, besides the storage capacity of the device?